# How to dynamically 'inject' environment variables defined in a file in run task with SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, environment-variables

I'am looking for a way to inject environment variables in an SBT task from a dynamic file.

For example : `sbt run -dev` or `sbt dev:run` or `sbt dev run` launches sbt run task after having injected environment variables defined in the file `conf/env/database.dev`

For the moment I have this code in `build.sbt` :

```
// ...
val dev = taskKey[Unit]("Dev config")
val local = taskKey[Unit]("Local config")

def setEnvVar(env: String) = {
  try{
    val split: Array[String] = (s"cat conf/env/database.$env" !!).split("\\n")
    val raw_vars = split.map(_.span(! _.equals('='))).map(x => x._1 -> x._2.tail).toList
    raw_vars foreach (v => {
      println(s"INJECTING ${v._1} = ${v._2}")
      javaOptions += s"-D${v._1}=${v._2}"
    })
  }catch{
    case e: Exception => println(s"Cannot inject env vars (${e.getMessage})")
  }
}


dev := {
  setEnvVar("dev")
}

local := {
  setEnvVar("local")
}
```

When I launch `sbt dev run`, I have the following result :

```
[info] Loading project definition from ...
[info] Set current project to ...
INJECTING PG_DB = qgd
INJECTING PG_HOST = localhost
INJECTING PG_PORT = 5432
INJECTING PG_USERNAME = ...
INJECTING PG_PASSWORD = ...
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 12 févr. 2016 10:46:10

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

But, when I go to `localhost:9000`, I can see that variables are not injected.

In my application.conf :

```
// ...
pg.db               = ${?PG_DB}
pg.host             = ${?PG_HOST}
pg.port             = ${?PG_PORT}
pg.default.username = ${?PG_USERNAME}
pg.default.password = ${?PG_PASSWORD}
// ...
```

Do you have any idea to solve my problem ?

Comment: I do not know why it is failing, is more an SBT question than a play framework. But why don't you follow the standard approach in play to define different config files per environment and run with -Dconfig.file=application-dev.conf ? Reference https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: Maybe you need to set fork := true, to start off a new process with these environment variables set.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
@JonasAnso : Yes, I agree. But my objective was to use something like `sbt dev run`. So, your suggest is a little bit too long for me.
@AjayPadala : It's a very good idea to fork. And it works well. (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AjayPadala suggested, I solved my problem by using **fork** processes.

I just updated my previous code with the following one :

```
fork := true // <=======================

val dev = taskKey[Unit]("Dev config")
val local = taskKey[Unit]("Local config")

def setEnvVar(env: String) = {
  try{
    val split: Array[String] = (s"cat conf/env/database.$env" !!).split("\\n")
    val raw_vars = split.map(_.span(! _.equals('='))).map(x => x._1 -> x._2.tail).toList
    val sysProp = System.getProperties // <=======================
    raw_vars foreach (v => {
      println(s"INJECTING ${v._1} = ${v._2}")
      sysProp.put(v._1, v._2) // <=======================
    })
    System.setProperties(sysProp) // <=======================
  }catch{
    case e: Exception => println(s"Cannot inject env vars (${e.getMessage})")
  }
}


dev := {
  setEnvVar("dev")
}

local := {
  setEnvVar("dev.default")
}
```